# Prove that the finite union of separable sets is separable.

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ and $B$ are separable, prove that $A \cup B$ is separable.

To attack this, I think I should use the definition of separability. If $A$ and $B$ are separable, then they contain a countable set that is dense in them. Therefore, the union of $A$ and $B$ must also contain this set, so $A \cup B$ is separable.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "must also contain this set"?  You need to show that $A\cup B$ contains a countable dense subset.  Hint:  If $F\subset A$ is countable dense, $G\subset B$ countable dense, then can you prove that $F\cup G \subset A\cup B$ is countable dense?

Comment: Huh, I think you are right to criticize my logic - there's no reason why the countable dense set in A should be the same one in B. So you are right to distinguish them as different sets.

Comment: As for your question, hmm... If F is a subset of A and G is a subset of B, then F union G is clearly a subset of A union B. Now, what I think you are asking is how can I prove that F union G is countable and dense in A union B.

Comment: To that end, it is a known theorem in topology that the finite union of countable sets is countable. But I am not sure how to prove that F union G is dense in A union B.

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking.  Note we don't only know that $F$ is a subset of $A$, $G$ a subset of $B$.  We have that $F$ is a countable dense subset of $A$, and $G$ is a countable dense subset of $B$.  (Hint:  $F\cup G$ is countable by a very simple argument, so you need to prove that $F\cup G$ is dense.)

Comment: What is the definition of $F\subset A$ dense?  In other words, what does it mean for a subset of $A$ to be dense in $A$?

Comment: Oh, we know that if a F is dense in A, then the closure of F contains A. Here, I need help. I am very weak in understanding closure.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the comment section above, let $F \subset A$ and $G \subset B$ be countable, dense subsets of $A,B$ respectively. It is well known that a countable union of countable sets is countable, so $F \cup G$ is countable. Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that $F \cup G$ is not dense in $A \cup B$. Then $\overline{F \cup G} \neq A \cup B$, which is to say for some $x \in A \cup B$, we know $x \notin \overline{F \cup G}$. This means $x$ is not a limit point of $\overline{F \cup G}$ so there must be an open set $U \subset A \cup B$ such that $$[F \cup G] \cap [U-\{ x\}] = \emptyset$$ Now use this open set $U$, the fact that $F \subset F\cup G$, and  $G \subset F \cup G$ and the equality above to form a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I think I know where to go from here!

Comment: Great! Let me know when you got it :)

Comment: Another approach, which I think may have been more confusing than instructive, is to first prove that $\overline{F\cup G} \supseteq \overline{F}\cup \overline{G}$

Comment: but $A\cup B = \overline{F} \cup \overline{G} \subset \overline{F\cup G}$ so doesn't have sense supose $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\notin \overline{F\cup G}$