# Countable union of separable subsets of a metric space is separable

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

This is a question from Irving Kaplansky's *Set theory and metric spaces*.

> Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, \cdots$ be subsets of a metric space $M$. Suppose each $A_i$ is separable. Prove that $\cup_i A_i$ is separable.

I found a related [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003373/prove-that-the-finite-union-of-separable-sets-is-separable) for finite unions.

For my question, here is my attempt.

For each $i$, since $A_i$ is separable, we can find a countable dense subset $D_i$ of $A_i$. I claim that $D = \cup_i D_i$ is a countable dense subset of $\cup_i A_i$.

First note that $D$ is a countable union of countable sets, and is therefore countable.

For density, let $\epsilon > 0.$ Let $y \in \cup_i A_i$. Then $y \in A_i$ for some $i$. By density of $D_i$ in $A_i$, there is $x \in D_i$ such that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$. Since $x \in \cup_i D_i$, we see that $D$ is dense in $\cup_i A_i$.

Is this correct? Would it work if the collection of subsets is uncountable? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is correct but does not work for uncountable collection. In that case the union of the $D_i$ is not necessarily countable because you are dealing with an uncountable index set. If it would work then every metric space could be proved to be separable (which is not the case).

Comment: Thank you for confirming! :)